# iMovie 10.1.12 - Faster Export to File

Tags: imovie

Is there a way to minimize time taken to Export to File a movie clip? Currently it's taking a long time. Is there a specific setting to switch on or off? Not reduction in resolution etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the new format for films (H.264) that will reduce the size of your film. That why it took you so long but the quality remains the same.